# MPAndroidChart library with lazy loading listview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, mpandroidchart

I'm doing a recycler listview that will display graphics with lazy loading.  When I first open the list, I display 10 items, and then when I get to the end of the list, I load 5 more items.

However, for these 5 items loaded later, the plotted graph is drawn thicker. I think it draws on it again. I do not know what the problem is. Does anyone have an idea about that?

[My chart should look like the first position. Then the item that I am lazily loaded is like the second position.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7vg9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loaded another five entries you need to call following method to reload your chartview:

```
yourDataSet.notifyDataSetChanged();  // update dataset for new values
chartView.notifyDataSetChanged();   // let the chart know it's data changed
chartView.invalidate();  // refresh the chart
```

For further queries and explanation please visit:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data